# Why do I need to install the EntityFrameworkCore nuget package when moving my project to a new machine?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nuget-package

Maybe I didn't install the package correctly to begin with, please let me know, but after I moved my project to a new machine, installed .Net Core SDK 3.1 (latest) and cloned my project from Github, I had to go and install this nuget package manually:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

When I first opened up the project in VS Code I had like 200+ errors for missing files.
I installed the EntityFrameworkCore package in my project folder and that fixed it.

QUESTION - I didn't have to install any of the other packages below (ex. SendGrid), so why this one?
Did I not install it correctly initially on my other computer? So maybe it didn't check in the reference or something? But the reference is in the .csproj file below!

Here are all the other packages I'm using and none had to be manually installed except
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.3

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="3.1.3" />


<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.6.0" />
<!-- <PackageReference Include="NetTopologySuite" Version="2.0.0" /> -->
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="CloudinaryDotNet" Version="1.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.12.0" />
```

Comment: may be the restore failed for that package.

Comment: as far as I'm aware, I never did a "dotnet restore", does it get performed automatically when I do something else?

Comment: yes during build. if you share your github repository, I can give it a try.